# using Timer Controls (i.e. setTimeout) in multiple loops

Tags: javascript

I know how to display characters in news ticker type fashion (1 at a time on a delay), but I can seem to figure out how to display ***multiple* news items**. For example:

1. I have an array of strings.
2. I'd like to **loop through *each item*** in the array, and...
3. and **for each item** (i.e. each string of text) in the array, I would **then** like to
4. **loop through *EACH CHARACTER*** in that string and...
5. display the character on screen **in 70ms intervals** (using setTimeout).
6. Once I've reached the last character in that string, I want to jump back to the previous loop (see #2) to continue **at an interval of 1 sec.** (again using setTimeout).

Below is my feeble (i.e. greenhorn) attempt at solving this problem. I can get at each string and so far just do a console.log on it. Cant seem to figure out how to steps 4 through 6.

Somebody shed some light on this please.

Thanks In Advance!

```
<body>

<p class="theText">This is test 1 of the text.</p>
<p class="theText">This is test 2 of the text.</p>
<p class="theText">This is test 3 of the text.</p>
<div id="textScroller"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var textScroller = function(scrollContainer){
    var container = document.getElementById(scrollContainer);
    var nodeContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('theText');

    // this function gets only the nodeValues from the nodeContainer array
    // and puts them in an array called textArray
    var getTextArray = function makeTextArray(theNodeArray){
        var textArray = [];
        for(var i=0;i<nodeContainer.length;i++){
            var container_text = nodeContainer[i].firstChild.nodeValue;
            textArray.push(container_text);
        }   
        return textArray;   
    };


    var textArray = getTextArray();

    /* 
        Right now the "showText" function just logs the string of text to the console.
        But the function SHOULD 
            [a] loop through each character in the CURRENT string and 
            [b] display the current character 
            [c] check if there are more characters and, if so...
            [d] display the next character in 70 milliseconds (i.e. setTimeout or setInterval)
            [e] if no more characters, go back to the function (loopArray) and get the next string
    */
    function showText(theString){
        console.log(theString);
    }

    // loop through and process each item in the array
    var l = 0;
    function loopArray(){
        var thisString = textArray[l];
        showText(thisString);
        if(l < textArray.length -1){
            setTimeout(loopArray,1000);
        }
        l++;        
    }       

    setTimeout(loopArray,1000);
}

textScroller('textScroller');           
</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple loops, you just need to remember which character you're up to in the current array item - if you've gone off the end then move on to the next item. Try something like the following:

```
var loopForever = false,
    itemIndex = 0,
    charIndex = 0;

function loopArray(){
   var currentItem = textArray[itemIndex];
   if (charIndex >= currentItem.length) {
      // move on to next item
      if (++itemIndex >= textArray.length) {
         // if looping forever go back to start of the item array,
         // otherwise return (in which case no new timeout will be set).
         if (loopForever)
            itemIndex = 0;
         else
            return;
      }
      charIndex = 0;
   }
   showText(currentItem.charAt(charIndex));
   // if at the end of the current item then delay 1000ms, otherwise 70ms
   setTimeout(loopArray, ++charIndex === currentItem.length ? 1000 : 70); 
}

setTimeout(loopArray,1000);
```

The above assumes that your other code successfully sets up `textArray` as an array of the strings you want to display (such that in your example `textArray` is `["This is test 1 of the text.","This is test 2 of the text.","This is test 3 of the text."]`).

Comment: Bravo! Well done and thank you. I have learned quite a bit from this code. thanks again!